# Question about functions $f: \mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $x$ is prime whenever $f(x)$ is prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, special-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{\mathbb{Z}^+} \to \mathbb{Z^+}$ be a function and suppose

$(\star)$ For all integers $x \geq 3$, if $f(x)$ is prime, then $x$ is prime.

A trivial example of such a function is the identity $f(x) = x$.  However, a possible non-trivial example which I have come across is
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \left\lfloor \frac{\cosh(x\ln(2 + \sqrt{3}))}{2}\right\rfloor.
\end{align*}

This function seems to satisfies $(\star)$ (see [OEIS A198196](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C%205%2C%207%2C%2011%2C%2013%2C%2017%2C%2019%2C%2079%2C%20151%2C%20199%2C%20233%2C%20251%2C%20317%2C%20863%2C%20971&language=english&go=Search)).  I have two questions:

1. How might one go about proving $f$ satisfies $(\star)$?  I'm not sure where to begin with this, and it seems like a difficult task.
2. Have functions with property $(\star)$ been studied before?

Thanks for any information you can give me.

---

**Edits:** I've composed the floor function with $f$, and added the condition to $(\star)$ that $x$ must be an integer.

Comment: Does $f$ also have the property that "if $x\geq3$ is prime, then $f(x)$ is prime"?

Comment: @Joe No.  For example, with $f$ as above, $f(23)$ is not prime.  It appears that as the primes $p$ get larger, it become more and more difficult for $f(p)$ to be prime, but I suspect that there are infinitely many primes $p$ with $f(p)$ prime.

Comment: Isn't $f(x)=\frac{(2-\sqrt{3})^{x}+(2+\sqrt{3})^{x}}{4}$. Also OEIS defines $f$ as the floor of this function, otherwise if $f(x)$ is prime, $x$ is probably sometimes irrational....Note here that this formula implies that, $f(n)$ satisfies, if I didn't make a mistake, the recurrence $$f(n+1)=4f(n)+f(n-1)$$ which may make the problem of studing for which integers $n$ is $f(n)$ prime easier. Going ro reals is a bit tricky though.

Comment: Yes. For example, $f(x)=17$ when $x=3.2038164\dots$, which is not prime.

Comment: @mattstokes: Okay, thanks for the info. Also, I take it that $f^{-1}$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions (or anything "nice" like that). Is that correct?

Comment: @Joe Let $y:= (2+\sqrt{3})^x$. Then, you can solve the quadratic equation $$y+\frac{1}{y}=4f(x)$$ for $y$, and take the logarithm, to find the formula of $f^{-1}(x)$.... Or you can express $\cosh^{-1}$ in terms of elementary functions.... Note that since $\cosh$ is even, you get two solutions , one being minus the other.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thank you for pointing this out!  I was trying to ditch the floor function here but looks like that wont work.

Comment: @NickS: I didn't realise that $f$ is not one-to-one, thanks. If we allow $f^{-1}$ to be multi-valued, we get that $$f^{-1}(x)=\pm\frac{\operatorname{arcosh}(2x)}{\log(2+\sqrt{3})}=\pm\frac{\log\left(2x+\sqrt{4x^2-1}\right)}{\log(2+\sqrt{3})} \, .$$(Although this is ignoring the fact that Matt has now defined $f$ using the floor function.)

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I realized that my previous comment doesn't make sense.  I think this can be saved if I add the condition that $x$ has to be an integer.

Comment: @NickS  You're right, as Gerald points out when $f(x) = 17$, $x$ is not an integer.  I've changed $(\star)$ so that $x$ is required to be an integer.  Thank you for also pointing out the recurrence relation!

Comment: @mattstokes If you restrict to $n$ being an integer, you have the recurrence $$a_{n+1}=4a_n+a_{n-1} \\
a_1=1 \\
a_0=\frac{1}{2}$$
and you want to show that $\lfloor a_n \rfloor$ is prime implies $n$ is prime. If I am not mistaken $a_n$ is integer for odd $n$ and half integer for even $n$. I wonder if finding separate recurrences for $\lfloor a_{2n} \rfloor$ and $a_{2n+1}$ may make the problem easier.

Comment: @NickS Thank you, I had not noticed the recurrence relation before.  Gives me something extra to play around with.

Comment: You might be interested in the notion of a divisibility sequence. This is a function from $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ to itself such that if $n \mid m$ then $f(n) \mid f(m)$. If $f(m)>1$ for $m>1$ then $f(n)$ being a prime implies $n$ is a prime. A classical example is $f(n)=2^n-1$, related to Mersenne numbers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As observed in comments, we have $f(n) = \lfloor g(n) \rfloor$ where $g(n) = \frac{\alpha^n + \alpha^{-n}}{4}$ and $\alpha = 2 + \sqrt{3}$.  From the recurrence $g(n+1) = 4 g(n) - g(n-1)$ we see that $g(n)$ is a half-integer when $n$ is even and an integer when $n$ is odd.  In fact we see from induction that for even $n$ we have $g(n) = \frac{1}{2} \hbox{ mod } 3$ and for odd $n$ we have $g(n) = 1 \hbox{ mod } 3$.  Hence for even $n$, $f(n)$ is divisible by $3$ and thus not prime except when $n=2$.  For odd $n$, we have $f(n)=g(n)$, and for odd $n,m$ we then have
$$ f(nm) = f(n) (\alpha^{n(m-1)} + \alpha^{n(m-3)} + \dots + \alpha^{n(1-m)})$$
thanks to the formula $a^m+b^m = (a+b)(a^{m-1} + a^{m-2} b + \dots + b^{m-1})$.  From the Galois group action interchanging $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{-1}$ we see that $\alpha^{n(m-1)} + \alpha^{n(m-3)} + \dots + \alpha^{n(1-m)}$ is an integer, and for $n,m \geq 3$ this integer is larger than $1$.  Thus $f(nm)$ is composite when $n,m \geq 3$ are odd, so the only remaining possible values of $n$ for which $f(n)$ can be prime are the primes.

In the language of [divisibility sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence), $f(n)$ is a divisibility sequence on the odd natural numbers, though not on the even ones.  In retrospect this is not so surprising given that $f$ is so similar to the Fibonacci sequence $F_n = \frac{\phi^n - \phi^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}$, which is well known to be a divisibility sequence.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Just one more related question: How much money would you bet on there being infinitely many primes $p$ such that $f(p)$ is prime?

Comment: This is comparable to the open question of whether there exist infinitely many Mersenne primes, or infinitely many Fibonacci primes.  Heuristics point in the direction of a positive answer to all these questions, but only barely (these heuristics predict that the number of primes in the first $x$ elements of each sequence grow only like $\log \log x$ or so), so I would not be as definitively certain of this as, say, the infinitude of twin primes.

Answer (score 4):

Too long for a comment.

If you are restricting to $n$ being an integer, unless I made a mistake, the problem can be rephrased as
Let
$$a_{n+1}=4a_n-a_{n-1} \\
a_1=1 \\
a_0=\frac{1}{2}$$

Then, show that $\lfloor a_n \rfloor$ is prime implies that $n$ is prime.

Here are some notes, I didn't check the details so there may be many mistakes.

**Note 1:** I think that $a_{2n} \in \mathbb Z +\frac{1}{2}$ and $a_{2n+1} \in \mathbb Z$. This implies that
$$
\lfloor a_{2n} \rfloor = a_{2n}-\frac{1}{2} \\
\lfloor a_{2n+1} \rfloor = a_{2n+1}
$$

This suggests splitting the problem into odd and even $n$.

**Note 2:** The odd $n's$. Let
$$
b_n=a_{2n+1}=\frac{(2-\sqrt{3})^{2n+1}+(2+\sqrt{3})^{2n+1}}{4}=\frac{(2-\sqrt{3})(7-4\sqrt{3})^{n}+(2+\sqrt{3})(7+4\sqrt{3})^{2n+1}}{4}
$$
I think that this is the solution to the recurrence
$$
b_{n+1}=14b_n-b_{n-1} \\
b_{1}= \mbox{something} \\
b_0=\mbox{something}
$$

The problem then becomes

**Question A** Show that $b_{n}$ prime implies that $2n+1$ is prime.

Similarly,
$$c_{n}=a_{2n}$$ is the solution to the same recurrence, with different innitial condition.

Setting
$$
d_{n}=c_n-\frac{1}{2} 
$$
we get
$$
c_{n}=d_n+\frac{1}{2}
$$
and hence the recurrence becomes
$$
c_{n+1}=14c_n-c_{n-1}  \Rightarrow
d_{n+1}=14d_n-d_{n-1}+6
$$
and the question becomes:

**Question B:** show that $d_n$ is not prime for $n \geq 2$.

There are some techniques of solving such problems for recurrences, so these comments could help or could be totally useless.

ANd keep in mind that there may be mistakes above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I believe the original recurrence relation is off since $f(3) =13$ but $a_{3}=19$.

Comment: Yea, $2 \pm \sqrt{3}$ are roots of $x^2-4x+1=0$ which means that the recurrence is $a_{n+1}=4a_n-a_{n-1}$. Got the wrong signs, will fix it :)